# How can I put a graphic marker next to an item using pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple menu:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>A</li>
    <li class="current">B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to put a big graphic marker (`<--`) next to the current item:

```
* A
* B <--
* C
```

How can I do that using just CSS, without altering the markup? My usual trick is setting the image as a background of the item, but this image is quite big, so that it gets cropped by the item’s bounding box. I stress that the marker is not a string, it’s an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this:

```
li.current:after {
   content: "<--";
   display: inline-block;
}
```

maybe giving some left margin, e.g. : http://jsbin.com/aluziv/1/

if the element itself is an image just load it as `background-image`

```
li.current:after {
   content: "";
   background: url(...) top left no-repeat;
   width: ...px;
   height: ...px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea I could turn the generated content into a regular styled block.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS `:before` or :`after` selectors. For example:

```
.current:after {
    content:'<--';
}
```

Example on jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/hr3Rv/

You can add additional styles to the `:after` block as required (it is a little restricted in what you can do with it, but for what you're asking, it's exactly right).

If the marker is an image, you can reference it like this:

```
.current:after {
    content:url('image.png');
}
```

Another alternative is to use an image font (for example, the [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) font). Include the font elsewhere in your CSS, and reference the appropriate character from the font:

```
.current:after {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f100"; //font-awesome's left double-arrow icon
}
```

(see the FontAwesome site for further instructions)

Answer (score 2):

Try the CSS `:after` selector. The following would [produce your result](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2UXu/1/) (writing "<--" after the current element):

```
li.current:after {
    content: "<--";
}
```

You can also insert an image:

```
li.current:after {
    content: url('arrow.png');
}
```